# How to iterate through rows of a column of a unknown data-frame in pyspark

Tags: python, apache-spark, pyspark, apache-spark-sql

I am new to Data Science and I am working on a simple self project using Google Colab. I took a data from a `something.csv` file and the file's columns are encrypted with `####`, so I don't know the names of the columns. I took

Here is my attempt to solve it using pyspark

```
df = spark.read.csv('something.csv', header=True)
col = df[df.columns[len(df.columns)-1]] #Taking last column of data-frame
```

Now I want to iterate through rows of 'col' column and print the rows that has a number less than 100. I searched other stackoverflow posts but didn't understand how to iterate through the column with no name.

Comment: Did you manage to select the column successfully? I think you could just use `col = df.iloc[:, -1]`.

Comment: @AMC I had to use `df[df.columns[len(df.columns)-1]]` instead of `col = df.iloc[:, -1]` because I was getting teh error stating "DataFrame object has no attribute iloc". I tried to solve it but couldn't. So I used the above method to extract the last column of the dataframe.

Comment: What Pandas version are you using?

Comment: @AMC I setup Spark on my colab environment using `!pip install pyspark
!pip install -U -q PyDrive
!apt install openjdk-8-jdk-headless -qq
import os`

Comment: Right, but which version of each library is installed?

Comment: On second thought, what is the type of `df` ?

Answer (score 1):

In pyspark use **`.filter`** method on dataframe to filter records < 100.

```
#sample data po column is int
df.show()
#+---+----+---+
#| id|name| po|
#+---+----+---+
#|  1|   2|300|
#|  2|   1| 50|
#+---+----+---+

last_col = df[df.columns[len(df.columns)-1]]

from pyspark.sql.functions import *

df.filter(last_col < 100).show()
#+---+----+---+
#| id|name| po|
#+---+----+---+
#|  2|   1| 50|
#+---+----+---+
```

---

**`UPDATE:`**

```
#getting rows into list
lst=df.filter(last_col < 100).select(last_col).rdd.flatMap(lambda x:x)
lst.collect()
#[50]

to get all rows into list
lst=df.filter(last_col < 100).rdd.flatMap(lambda x:x)
lst.collect()
#[u'2', u'1', 50]
```

Comment: Thanks, But do you know how to get their row numbers because I want to store those row numbers in a list.

Comment: I am getting an error saying "cannot resolve '`po`' given input columns:"

Comment: Try with `df.filter(last_col < 100).select(last_col).rdd.flatMap(lambda x:x).collect()`